# Reindex on both index and columns at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I often need to reindex dataframe on both the index and columns of another dataframe, i.e.

`df_out = df2.reindex(df1.index).reindex(df1.columns,axis='columns')`

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  As in quicker execution. Or less verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `reindex` setting index and columns in one call

[`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) can take both `index` and `columns` parameters in one call to do exactly that:

```
df2.reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
```

---

#### `reindex_like` to reindex just like another dataframe (both axes):

```
df2.reindex_like(df1)
```

Let's check with the same example from the docs:

```
print(df)
           http_status  response_time
Firefox            200           0.04
Chrome             200           0.02
Safari             404           0.07
IE10               404           0.08
Konqueror          301           1.00
```

---

```
new_index = ['Safari', 'Iceweasel', 'Comodo Dragon', 'IE10','Chrome']
new_columns = ['http_status', 'some_other_col']
df.reindex(index=new_index, columns=new_columns)

                  http_status  some_other_col
Safari               404.0             NaN
Iceweasel              NaN             NaN
Comodo Dragon          NaN             NaN
IE10                 404.0             NaN
Chrome               200.0             NaN
```

Comment: Definitely less verbose. And 10 times faster on a 1000 x 1000 dataframe. It would be nice if you could just do df2.reindex(df1) in this case

Comment: Hah now that you say it came to my mind. You have `df2.reindex_like(df1)` @skypi

Comment: reindex_like is exactly what I was looking for here. But on my random 1000 x 1000 dataframe reindex_like is 4 times faster than calling reindex twice, once with index once with columns, but 3 times slower than your original answer of specifying both index and columns in call to reindex. I expected it to be faster than reindex.

Comment: Huh interesting... I would have expected that too @skypi Anyways, since it is less verbose, definitely worth leaving here